# Crystal Reports XI and MySQL Stored Procedure with Parameters

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, crystal-reports, report

I am having a problem with a Crystal Report that displays data from a MySQL table.  I am  currently gathering the data directly from the table, however when the users try to input parameters, problems arise such as:

1. null values for parameters returning errors
2. parameters not working as specified

I then created a stored procedure to return data if a parameter is empty and will make the MySQL server do the work rather than the Crystal Reports server.

However Crystal Reports doesn't appear to recognize this and I am having some trouble displaying the results of the procedure.

Here is a copy of the procedure i am using:

```
Create Procedure sp_report
(IN @param1 varchar(64),
 IN @param2 varchar(64),
 IN @param3 int )

Begin

IF @param1 is null AND @param2 is null AND @param3 is null Then
  Select * from tblData
ELSE IF @param1 is null AND @param2 is not null AND @param3 is not null then 
  Select * from tblData where field3 = @param3 and field2 = @param2
ELSE IF @param1 is not null AND @param2 is not null AND @param3 is  null then 
  Select * from tblData where field2 = @param2 and field1 = @param1
ELSE IF @param1 is not null AND @param2 is null AND @param3 is not null then 
  Select * from tblData where field3 = @param3  and field1 = @param1 
ELSE IF @param1 is not null AND @param2 is null AND @param3 is null then 
  Select * from tblData where field1 = @param1
ELSE IF @param1 is  null AND @param2 is not null AND @param3 is  null then 
  Select * from tblData where  field2 = @param2
ELSE IF @param1 is null AND @param2 is null AND @param3 is not null then
  Select * from tblData where field3 = @param3
ELSE IF @param1 is not null AND @param2 is not null AND @param3 is not null then 
  Select * from tblData where field3 = @param3 and field2 = @param2 and field1 = @param1
END;
```

Is there an easier way to do this or am I doing something wrong?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: crystal reports doesn't recognize the stored procedure? I don't use mysql, but maybe use a different database driver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm reading your IF tree correctly, I think you could do this instead (I'm a T-SQL guy, so I can't confirm if this will run in MySQL):

```
SELECT *
  FROM tblData
 WHERE ((field1=@param1) OR (@param1 is null))
   AND ((field2=@param2) OR (@param2 is null))
   AND ((field3=@param3) OR (@param3 is null))
```

Comment: Thank you!  We have updated the procedure to this and it works.  Now the problem lies with Crystal Reports....

SELECT * 
  FROM tblData
 WHERE (field1 = @param1 OR @param1 is null) 
   AND (field2 = @param2 OR @param2 is null) 
   AND (field3 = @param3 OR @param3 is null);

Answer (score 1):

I can't help with the mySQL part, but I do something very similar with both SQL Server and Oracle.  Instead of a series of IF statements covering every possible combination of null/not null parameters, I do something like this:

```
select * from tblData where (field1 = @param1 or @param1 is null) and
(field2 = @param2 or @param2 is null) and
(field3 = @param3 or @param3 is null)
```

That covers any mix of null and non-null parameters without exponentially increasing the number of IF statements as the number of parameters increases.

This is a complete guess on my part, but in Oracle you need to declare a cursor as an IN OUT parameter for SPs to work with Crystal.  Could mySQL have the same requirement?  Here's a sample of an Oracle SP:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE      SomeProcedure
(
    param1               IN         VARCHAR2 DEFAULT null,
    param2               IN         VARCHAR2 DEFAULT null,
    REPORT_CURSOR        IN OUT     CrystalPkg.CrystalCursor
)
AS
BEGIN

    OPEN REPORT_CURSOR FOR
    SELECT blahblah from blah...
```

Comment: Thank you!  The procedure has been update and is currently:
SELECT * 
  FROM tblData
 WHERE (field1 = @param1 OR @param1 is null) 
   AND (field2 = @param2 OR @param2 is null) 
   AND (field3 = @param3 OR @param3 is null);

We are looking into the cursor suggestion as we are still having a problem with the Crystal Report.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * 
from tblData 
where field1 like isnull(@param1,'%%' 
and field2 like isnull(@param2,'%%')
and field3 like isnull(@param3,'%%')
```